# How can I get the value of a dynamic wildcard child key returned through an .onWrite cloud function event?

Tags: json, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase cloud function observer set up on a path with the following JSON nesting structure:

```
$myUID: {
     places : {
        $placeID: {
            $myUID_checkedIn = "false";                                 [line4]
            $someoneElseUID_checkedIn = "true";
        },
     }
   }
```

The observer is set up to observe :

```
exports.observePlaces = functions.database.ref('users/{userID}/places/{placeID}').onWrite((change,context)
```

I'd like to retrieve the value of the dynamic key "$myUID_checkedIn", from the JSON structure in [line4].

I tried using something like:

```
const uid = context.params.userID; //VALID
const dataSnapshot = change.after.val(); //VALID
const isCheckedIn = dataSnapshot.(`${uid}_checkedIn`); //INVALID     [line11]
```

However, I'm unable to retrieve the value for the dynamic key in [line11] using this approach.

Is this possible to achieve given the way my data is structured?

If so, how should I go about retrieving this value?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript proper indexing of property names when they are not literal identifiers.  Square brackets are used for this:

```
const isCheckedIn = datasnapShot[`${uid}_checkedIn`]
```

Comment: Am I following correctly?  
1. "context.params.userID" gets the "uid" key node
2. "context.params.placeID" gets "placeID" key node. 

I'm already able to retrieve these values successfully. 

I'm trying to figure out how to get the value of the "$myUID_checkedIn" key, using the returned "uid" value

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I'm looking for! I'll test it out and report back.